# What are “weak” and “strong” output-input bit dependencies?

Tags: terminology, diffusion

Section 3.3.5 of the paper “Schwaemm and Esch: Lightweight Authenticated Encryption and
Hashing using the Sparkle Permutation Family” (the link to PDF can be found in [this page](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/lightweight-cryptography/finalists)) contains the following text:

> Alzette provides very fast diffusion. In particular, all outputs bits depend on all the input bits
> after 4 rounds, though this dependency can be very weak. After 8 rounds however, we have that
> all output bits strongly depend on all the input bits.

Question: what are “weak” and “strong” dependencies? I thought that the bit dependency was either *present* or *absent*. If it is present, how to *measure* it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be various measures of bit dependency. A classical measure would be how close the process is to achieving what Claude Shannon termed [diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_and_diffusion#Diffusion), which is sometimes termed the [strict avalanche criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect#Strict_avalanche_criterion). In this case we measure the proportion of input/output pairs for which changing the selected input bit changes the selected output bit. If the proportion is 0 this would be independence, if the proportion is close to 1/2 this would be diffusion/SAC, if the proportion is close to 0 this would be called weak dependence, if the proportion is close to 1/2 this would be called strong dependence.

For example consider the four-bit to one-bit Boolean function
$$y=x_1x_2+x_0x_1x_2x_3$$
it is easy to exhaustively check that flipping the $x_0$ or $x_3$ inputs changes the value of $y$ for 2 possible input values out of 16. This is dependency, but quite weak.

By contrast, for the function
$$z=x_0x_1+x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_0$$
it is easy to check that flipping any bit changes the value of $z$ for 8 of the possible input values out of 16. This is strong dependency.

There's a question of what we should term the cases where the proportion that change on flipping is close to 1.

Comment: full dependent?